# Delete one line from my text file

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\teste.txt"))
{            
    string numcont = _transaction.PartyFederalTaxID;
    double numenc = _transaction.BillToPartyID;
    double numfatura = _transaction.TransDocNumber;
    DateTime data = _transaction.CreateDate;
    double valor = _transaction.TotalAmount;
    short zona = transaction.Zone.ZoneID;
    //preçoantesdisc mal
    double precoantesdisc = _transaction.TotalPaymentDiscountAmount;
    double preconet = transaction.Details.TotalAdvancementNetAmount;
    double quantidade = transaction.Details.Count;
    double bonus = _transaction.TotalPaymentDiscountAmount;
    string valorStr = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    foreach (ItemTransactionDetail detail in transaction.Details)
    {
        var item = MyApp.DSOCache.ItemProvider.GetItem(detail.ItemID, MyApp.SystemSettings.BaseCurrency);
        double taxRate = MyApp.DSOCache.TaxesProvider.GetTaxRateFromTaxableGroupID(detail.TaxableGroupID, "PRT", "CON");
        string barcode = item.BarCode;
        item = null;

        writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")};{valorStr};{zona};{Environment.NewLine}{barcode};{taxRate};{precoantesdisc};{preconet};{quantidade};{bonus}");
    }

}
MessageBox.Show("gravou");
```

It writes some variables into a text file. When I add 2 or more items into it, the text will repeat the first line. I need to delete the first line on the third line. (By first and second line, I mean until the `{Environment.NewLine}`).
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the current result is and what it should be?

Comment: Change your process.  Write the transaction items outside of the loop, and the transaction details inside the loop. Then you don't have to go back and muck with the text file.

Comment: @Laoujin yes, sure, is something like this:
123456789; 0; 126; 28-07-2017;7.98;5;
hdazs;23;0;0;3;0
123456789; 0; 126; 28-07-2017;7.98;5;
hdazs;23;0;0;3;0

I want to delete that second "123456789; 0; 126; 28-07-2017;7.98;5;"

Comment: Unrelated but look into using `decimal` instead of `double` for money amounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in full control of the duplicated line, so you should fix *that* instead of going back and trying to remove it from the result:

```
writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data:dd/MM/yyyy)};{valorStr};{zona};");
foreach (ItemTransactionDetail detail in transaction.Details)
{
    var item = MyApp.DSOCache.ItemProvider.GetItem(detail.ItemID, MyApp.SystemSettings.BaseCurrency);
    double taxRate = MyApp.DSOCache.TaxesProvider.GetTaxRateFromTaxableGroupID(detail.TaxableGroupID, "PRT", "CON");
    string barcode = item.BarCode;
    //item = null;  //not necessary - GC will take care of this

    writer.WriteLine($"{barcode};{taxRate};{precoantesdisc};{preconet};{quantidade};{bonus}");
}
```